# Task Scheduler not running python script from batch file, which works when started manually

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a Python script through Windows Task Scheduler by making a batch file.

Here's what I tried.

1. Normally putting python location in program/script and specifying the python file in arguments in task scheduler.
2. Trying through batch file

   ```
   start C:\Python27\pythonw.exe C:\Users\...\time_convert.py
   pause
   ```

   ```
   Call C:\Python27\pythonw.exe C:\...\time_convert.py
   pause
   ```

   ```
   C:\Python27\pythonw.exe C:\Users\...\time_convert.py
   pause
   ```

Also when I run the batch file manually it works fine. But not through task scheduler.

I can see a CMD window pops but a new text file doesn't gets created as per the `.py` script.

Here's the demo `.py` script:

```
print("done")
f=open("ay.txt",'w')
f.write("hi")
f.close()
```

Comment: The py file has full permission for everyone

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full path to the file, not just a relative path? It could be that the current working directory for the task is different from what you expected.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't written the file, but you're just not looking for it in the correct location? When you run a batch file as a scheduled task, the current working directory is not necessarily the same as when it is run directly or from the Command Prompt. Start by performing a search for the file, `Where/R C:\ ay.txt`, and let us know if it was found. Please also let us know where you want the text file to be located upon completion of the task.

Comment: This text file was just a example. I wanted to know performing scheduling of python script so I used this file write demo code to know if it is working. Let me search for the file

Comment: It was complete path @Ralf

Comment: @Compo I searched and no such file was found.

Comment: UPDATE: I solved it by adding a cd command to point to desktop and after that I invoked the python command. I didn't know that current working directory can get changed when we run through task scheduler